# getClass().getResource() only works with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, nullpointerexception, resources

I'm building a JavaFx application with Gradle on Windows 10. I created the project with the Gradle init task so the directory structure is

```
src
|--- main
     |--- java
     |    |--- thomas/software/helloworld/App.java (Main class)
     |    |--- thomas/software/helloworld/MainViewController.java (extends JavaFX Application)
     |--- resources
          |--- imgs/    (some images)
          |--- layout/  (fxml files)
```

In my controller I try to load the layout file:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                    getClass().getResource("../../../layout/main.fxml").toURI().toURL());
```

And I load images like this:

```
path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("imgs/question.png").toExternalForm();
```

Both ways work interchangibly when I'm running the project with `gradle run` or `gradlew run`.

My problem is when I run `gradlew distZip` the resulting distribution, run from the generated batch file can't find the layout file and throws a null pointer exception.

The structure of the generated jar file in build/libs and in the zip file in build/distributions is identical and looks like follows:

```
imgs/ (images are there)
layout/ (layout file also there)
META-INF/ 
thomas/software/helloworld/ (everything there as well)
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9099'
    }
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter API for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter Engine for testing.
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = 'thomas.software.helloworld.App'
}

test {
    // Use junit platform for unit tests
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Java Version 13
Gradle Version 6.1.

What am I missing?

Comment: In a local build, your file is exposed on the actual file structure. In a dist, it's within the archive, and either needs to be accessed as a stream (and not a URI/URL), or placed into the local file structure as a file, and then accessed as a URI/URL.

Comment: First of all, `Class#getResource(String)` already returns a `URL` so calling `toURI().toURL()` on the result is redundant. As for your problem, the `getResource` API does not support "navigating up" (i.e. `..`). It works when executed from Gradle because your code is on the actual file system of the host operating system, but once packaged in a JAR file the `..` will stop working. Note that the fact `..` works when your application is not packaged in a JAR file is an _implementation detail_ and is not guaranteed by the documentation.

Comment: Since all your FXML files appear to be in a package named `layout`, the calls to access those FXML files should all look something like: `getClass().getResource("/layout/<fxml-file-name>.fxml")`. Note the leading `/`. As documented by [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), a leading `/` makes it an _absolute_ name.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Slaw and @Compass. It works with. The relevant bits of the code:

```
var instream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("layout/main.fxml");
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(this);
loader.load(instream);
```

Comment: Two things: (1) Don't forget to close the `InputStream` when done with it–see the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html); (2) Note if your FXML file uses any relative paths (e.g. `@../styles/app.css`) then you'll have to use a `URL` with the `FXMLLoader`, instead of an `InputStream`, so it has a location to resolve relative paths against.